# insert string variable into echo

Tags: php, javascript

This seems like a fairly simple question, but I've been searching through google and can't find a solution.

```
function showJQueryAlert() {
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
                <script src="functions.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { JQueryAlert("INSERT MESSAGE HERE!", 120, false); }); </script>';
```

outputs the popup with the message "INSERT MESSAGE HERE!". But

```
function showJQueryAlert($message) {
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
                <script src="functions.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { JQueryAlert('.$message.', 120, false); }); </script>';
```

where $message is "INSERT MESSAGE HERE!", fails to output the popup. I've tried all sorts of combinations. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you forgot some quotes:

```
JQueryAlert("'.$message.'", 120, false);
```